# c comparing file sizes using fstat issue

Tags: c, file, filesize, stat, fstat

My code comparing 2 file sizes seems to behave as if `keyfile` > `sourcefile`. Is there something missing from the code below and what can I change? The two files I'm using for testing are 3kb keyfile and 14kb sourcefile, which should activate the last `if` statement provided below.

```
/* Get size of sourcefile. */
if((sourcefile = fopen(argv[1], "rb"))== NULL)
{
printf("Can't open source file.\n");
printf("Please enter a valid filename.\n");
printf("USAGE: OTP <source file> <output file> <keyfile>\n");
return (1);
}

fflush(sourcefile);
fstat(fileno(sourcefile), &statbuf);
fclose(sourcefile);

/* Get size of keyfile. */
if((keyfile = fopen(argv[3], "rb"))== NULL)
{
printf("Can't open keyfile.\n");
printf("Please enter a valid filename.\n"); 
printf("USAGE: OTP <source file> <output file> <keyfile>\n");
return(1);

fflush(keyfile);
fstat(fileno(keyfile), &keybuf);
fclose(keyfile);
}

/* Open necessary files. */
keyfile=fopen(argv[3], "rb");
sourcefile=fopen(argv[1], "rb");
destfile=fopen(argv[2], "wb");

/* Check if keyfile is the same size as, or bigger than the sourcefile */
if((keybuf.st_size) < (statbuf.st_size))
{
printf("Source file is larger than keyfile.\n");
printf("This significantly reduces cryptographic strength.\n");
printf("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N)\n");
scanf("%c", &ans);
if(ans == 'n' || ans == 'N')
    {
    return (1);
    }
if(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
    {
    printf("Proceeding with Encryption/Decryption.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to open your files twice...

Comment: ah yeah, you mean under /*opening necessary files*/? could do without the keyfile and source file there. edit coming up.

Comment: Nonononono. Take out the `fclose`s before `/* opening necessary files */`. you don't need them since you just re-open the file anyway. Then remove the `fopen`s of keyfile and sourcefile under aforementioned comment.

Comment: Also, you don't check if `destfile` could be opened. This will fail if the specified file couldn't be written to (permission errors etc).

Comment: Capture the return value from fstat, and make an appropriate error message, if you get a negative value. And why call fflush() before fstat()?

Comment: The comment above the if where you compare the file sizes is the other way round than your actual test.

Comment: @halex - the OP is asking why it acts the opposite way (i.e. he's asking why it is acting as if keyfile.size > statbuf.size).

Comment: ok, so my code wasn't as good as I thought haha. Would it be too much trouble to edit your answer with the changes to the code? I think I got it, but just to be sure you know:) I appologize for my newbieness but you've gotta learn somehow :) @slugonamission

Comment: Since you actually tried to implement it yourself and want verification, sure. See my updated answer. Hope it reads alright.

Comment: @Cœur this post is just one big typo, you should've cast CV instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you only `fstat` the keyfile if it fails to open. Move your curly brace up. Also, as an optimisation of forms, don't open the file, stat it, close it and re-open it. Just don't close it and carry on.

So, since you asked

```
/* Get size of sourcefile. */
if((sourcefile = fopen(argv[1], "rb"))== NULL)
{
printf("Can't open source file.\n");
printf("Please enter a valid filename.\n");
printf("USAGE: OTP <source file> <output file> <keyfile>\n");
return (1);
}

fflush(sourcefile);
//fstat(fileno(sourcefile), &statbuf);   // <-- this is not needed
//fclose(sourcefile);                    // <-- this is not needed

/* Get size of keyfile. */
if((keyfile = fopen(argv[3], "rb"))== NULL)
{
printf("Can't open keyfile.\n");
printf("Please enter a valid filename.\n"); 
printf("USAGE: OTP <source file> <output file> <keyfile>\n");
return(1);
    }                                     // <-- this brace is new (well, moved) (1)

fflush(keyfile);
//fstat(fileno(keyfile), &keybuf);    // <-- not needed
//fclose(keyfile);                    // <-- not needed
//}                                     // <-- this brace has moved up 4 lines to (1)

/* Open necessary files. */
keyfile=fopen(argv[3], "rb");
sourcefile=fopen(argv[1], "rb");
destfile=fopen(argv[2], "wb");

/* Check if keyfile is the same size as, or bigger than the sourcefile */
if((keybuf.st_size) < (statbuf.st_size))
{
printf("Source file is larger than keyfile.\n");
printf("This significantly reduces cryptographic strength.\n");
printf("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N)\n");
scanf("%c", &ans);
if(ans == 'n' || ans == 'N')
    {
    return (1);
    }
if(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
    {
    printf("Proceeding with Encryption/Decryption.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to `fflush` it. You've not written anything to it.

Comment: the internet should have more people like you haha. superhero(ish) =P